# OsCommerce Cart Becomes Empty When Trying to Login

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, oscommerce

Currently I am working on a Wordpress and OsCommerce site. The Wordpress site is a product catalogue site from where user will select product model and that particular product (under that model) will be added to the OsCommerce cart.

The above mentioned things work perfectly. The problem is that, when someone trying to login before going to the checkout page, all selected products of the OsCommerce cart will lost, and the cart becomes empty.

I have no idea why it's happening. Also, I have not much idea on OsCommerce platform.

May you please help me regarding this ? Let me know, if you need any other information.

Could not find much information on google and stackoverflow regarding this issue, and also not on OsCommerce.

Please help.